# What is a reasonable number of grad schools to apply to for a PhD in computer science?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, computer-science

I'm applying straight out of undergrad, and I'm not sure how many schools I should apply to.

Comment: Where are you applying to? How strong candidate are you?

Comment: I applied to six.  (Got into four of them.)

Comment: My undergrad institution is an Ivy League, and my GPA is around 3.7. I've done research in three research groups, so my recommendations will come from research advisors. I'm working on my honors thesis that I hope to submit for publication at a workshop later in the year. Have not taken the GRE or thought about my SOP yet.

Comment: This has no best answer. Many people really focus on tailoring their application to only a few (2-5) Universities, while others apply to many 15+. It depends on whether you know what what you want to do, who you want to work with, and many many other factors.

Comment: If you can pull off a decent GRE, your application would be a shoe in at most tier-1 research universities (so, say, the top 50 universities in the US). So unless you plan on applying exclusively to Harvard, MIT, Berkeley and Columbia, and if you choose a few of the better public universities, then you shouldn't have to write a whole lot of applications. I'm not going to suggest any concrete number, but I'd think somewhere at fewer than 10 is probably safe nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However many schools you find that have academics that you want to work with.

Research is like riding a bicycle.  You can obviously do it.  The application process for graduate school is mostly to vet applicants for those who can't ride the bicycle.  Therefore, the important next step for you is to find someone you will jive well with.  Applying to graduate schools should be more about that: find a professor that you'd be willing to enter into a serious personal relationship with.

With that being said, I have friends who applied to 9, 3 schools in 3 tiers: "dream schools", "realistic schools", and "satisfactory schools".

I applied to one.  I found a professor I really liked and started an email correspondence with him 3 months before I even applied.  When applications came around, there wasn't a question of where I would apply or whether I would get in.

Oh, and I'm a 4th year CS PhD candidate.